# How to get EOFException from FileInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am making the project about data compression(using Huffman Algorithm). The project is still in revision. I have run into very interesting problem. I need to read byte by byte from a binary file. I have got this file FileInputHelper that realize few methods:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileInputHelper implements Closeable {
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    private BufferedReader fileBufferedReader;

    public FileInputHelper(File file) throws IOException {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    }


    public byte readByte() throws IOException {
        return (byte)fileInputStream.read();
    }

    public char read() throws IOException {
        return (char)fileInputStream.read();
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return fileBufferedReader.readLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException{
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

But when the binary file end, method should return -1. Of course, it should be so. But there is some tests, where there are bytes, that are equal -1, but are not the last. 
As you understand, this is really critical. If in mid I read -1, I will think that there is end of the file. But it is not. Is there any ways to solve this problem? Can I get EOFException? And if my code is bad, I would like to listen your advice.

Comment: Hint: There is a reason why `InputStream` returns `int`: it can return values from -1 to 255 (well, it could as well return `short`, but it doesn't). If a byte is -1, it was 255 once before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `char` is unsigned, while `byte` is signed. Basically, where is a specific character (`0xffff`) which maps to `-1` when converted to a byte. This is also why the `read()` method on InputStream returns an integer, even though you are getting a byte or char.

One way to handle this issue is to check if `read()` returned `-1` before converting it to a byte or char. Then, if `read()` does return `-1`, you can throw an EOFException, and catch that. e.g.,

```
int cur = fileInputStream.read();
if(cur == -1) {
    throw new EOFException("End of input reached");
}else {
    return (char) cur;
}
```

However, catching exceptions is not intended as a way to indicate that an operation has completed normally. One way to handle this that avoids this is to buffer a character / byte, and add an `available()` method, as below.

```
public class FileInputHelper implements Closeable {
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    private BufferedReader fileBufferedReader;
    private int next;

    public FileInputHelper(File file) throws IOException {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        next = fileInputStream.read();
    }


    public byte readByte() throws IOException {
        int cur = next;
        next = fileInputStream.read();
        if(cur == -1) {
            throw new IOException("End of file reached");
        }
        return (byte) cur;
    }

    public char read() throws IOException {
        int cur = next;
        next = fileInputStream.read();
        if(cur == -1) {
            throw new IOException("End of file reached");
        }
        return (char) cur;
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return fileBufferedReader.readLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException{
        fileInputStream.close();
    }

    // Returns true if there are more chars / bytes to read.
    public boolean available() {
        return next != -1;
    }

}
```

This will have issues with how the file is read, if you use both the `read()`/`readByte()` and `readLine()` methods, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's why `InputStream.read()` declares return type `int` when actually reading `byte`. Only the lower byte of `int` is used for data. If you read `-1` byte then it will return `255` and you have to manually cast it down to `byte`.

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{1, 0, -1});
int read;
while ((read = in.read()) > -1) {
    System.out.println("As int: " + read + ", as byte: " + (byte) read);
}
```

Is going to output:

```
As int: 1, as byte: 1
As int: 0, as byte: 0
As int: 255, as byte: -1
```

You probably don't want to use `char` in your `public char read()` method because `char` is unsigned and can't hold `-1`. Returning `int` and following the usual convention is more readable.

Comment: Okay. And what difference between getting end of file and just -1 in this way?

Comment: `byte` -1 is read as positive `int` 255.  `int` -1 is an end of stream.